# How to scrape text from website with a "Show more" attribute in R?

Tags: r

Hello Stack overflow community,

There is a website with financial data Investing.com which offers data points and forecasts for certain economic variables.

For whoever is further interested, the exact URL with the info I want to **scrape** is [here](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/eia-crude-oil-inventories-75).

My objective is to **scrape** this information; however, the table in which the information is displayed contains a "Show more" attribute at the end. When I click on it, six new elements appear at a time. I am seeking a way in which I can uncollapse fifty or more elements at a time and then **scrape** them in R.

I know how to **scrape** text from websites but I do not know how to work around the "Show more" attribute.

I have tried to modify the Java code of the website albeit unsuccessfully. My knowledge on Java is limited yet.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If the webpage is dynamic, you'll need a headless browser to scrape it, I think. Take a look at [splashr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/vignettes/intro_to_splashr.html) perhaps?

Comment: I tried to get into the weeds of splashr but it requires Docker and, in turn, the latter, I believe, requires Window 10 Pro which unfortunately I cannot count on. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't follow. Does `splasher` need docker to execute or to install? And as far as I know, docker is available on all major operating systems (namely Windows, MacOS, and Linux). I'm not aware of any other options myself, unfortunately.

Comment: The need of having Docker is my interpretation of the following lines within the link you sent to splashr: "Once you have Docker working, you can follow the Splash installation guidance to manually obtain, start and stop Splash docker containers. There must be a running, accessible Splash instance for splashr to work."
I followed the instructions with and without Docker and couldn't make it work. Thank you for trying anyway!

Comment: please include your current code.

Comment: You don't need to automate a browser. httr (possibly rvest) will suffice as the page uses XHR POST to get more rows which is easy to replicate in R. No cookies are required.

Comment: That sounds very interesting, QHarr. Why don't you elaborate a little bit more on how to replicate it in R? My code so far resembles that from the comment of ASH beneath, and it only obtains the table from the cover of the website, so to speak. Now I need to trigger that "Show more" optionality in an automatic manner so that I can capture more rows.

Comment: Open the network tab of browser then click the show more. You will see an xhr POST appear. All the info you need is there. You can right click on the request and copy as curl bash then paste into https://curl.trillworks.com/ under R option. You can then refine that query to remove unnecessary info such as the cookies. Extract the total results count and perform a loop altering params |body appropriately to get all results.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/eia-crude-oil-inventories-75"

page <- read_html(url)
nodes <- html_nodes(page, "table") # you can use Selectorgadget to identify the node
table <- html_table(nodes[[1]]) # each element of the nodes list is one table that can be extracted
head(table)
```

Result:

```
  Release Date  Time  Actual Forecast Previous   
1 Dec 27, 2019 11:00 -5.474M  -1.724M  -1.085M NA
2 Dec 18, 2019 10:30 -1.085M  -1.288M   0.822M NA
3 Dec 11, 2019 10:30  0.822M  -2.763M  -4.856M NA
4 Dec 04, 2019 10:30 -4.856M  -1.734M   1.572M NA
5 Nov 27, 2019 10:30  1.572M  -0.418M   1.379M NA
6 Nov 20, 2019 10:30  1.379M   1.543M   2.219M NA
```

Comment: This procedure, ASH, gets me half way to the goal. Still I need to figure out to trigger the "Show more" option beneath the table so that rather than obtaining 6 rows I can obtain 500, for example.